# Sending attachement with JavaMail needs long time

Tags: java

I want to send attachemnd (pdf) to an email address with JavaMail. But sendig needs about 5 minutes...too long of course. The file is only 700kB big. So what can i do that this problem is solved? Following is my code. THX

The main part...

```
 ByteArrayDataSource ds = null;
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        byte[] bytearray;
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:/Serviceantrag_Kopie_befuellt1.pdf"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        int length = 0;
        try {
            while ((length = in.read(b)) != -1) {
                bao.write(b, 0, length);
            }
            bao.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        bytearray = bao.toByteArray();

        try {
            ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytearray, "application/pdf");
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Set From: header field of the header.
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(USERNAME));

    // Set To: header field of the header.
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(USERNAME));
    message.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf;charset=UTF-8");
    // Set Subject: header field
    message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

    // Create the message part
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    // Now set the actual message
    messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");

    // Create a multipar message
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // Set text message part
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // Part two is attachment
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    String filename = "D:/Serviceantrag_Kopie.pdf";

    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // Send the complete message parts
    message.setContent(multipart);

    // Send message
    Transport.send(message);

    System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
```

**EDIT**

I've take a picture of the sending about in the console. Take a look at the time...

[image]

Comment: How big is the PDF?

Comment: Have edit my question

Comment: One option: Set the JavaMail session to debug and check the timing in the output (redirect to logfile and read later). What is your connection from sending program to the SMTP server? Is the server limiting the transfer rate for mails over a certain size?

Comment: @Konrad: THX for your answer. But i don't understod it. The sending needs 5 minutes, so  what can read from the log file?

Comment: You may see if the server response is slow or something this way. Did you try another mail server for a test?

Comment: No din't. If i send the mail without the attachement...all works fine and fast. So only the pdf file needs the long time...

Comment: What is with my other two questions? What is your transfer rate of your connection to the mail server? Alternative generate a 700kB text message and check timing.

Comment: I have also generate a file (pdf) which has picutres and text inside. The file is an interactive pdf which was generated by Adobe DC. And the file before was also send under 10 seconds. But it has only 2 sites. This one has 5 sites and contains pictures and text.

Comment: What version of JavaMail do you use? What MTA product? Do you use an authenticated session? Do you send exactly one email or many emails in sequence?